# How can my drow-blooded half-elf overcome light blindness?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

I'm building a half-elf with the drow-blooded racial trait. What items or spells (or anything else), can my character use to overcome light blindness?

I came across [this great question and answer related to D&D 3.5](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/40957/what-methods-are-there-to-remove-prevent-or-otherwise-safeguard-from-penalties). What Pathfinder items and spells exist?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick google search on d20pfsrd.com reveals:

- The item *[lenses of darkness](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/h-l/lenses-of-darkness)*
- The 2nd level spell *[protective penumbra](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/protective-penumbra)*

There's also the unofficial cantrip *[penumbra](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/rare-cantrips)* (from a Paizo blog supplement to Ultimate Magic).  The higher level spell does offer protection to vampires and such as well, so maybe the cantrip is justified.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered blindsense or blindsight?

**Classes**: Oracle (Oracles Curse - Clouded Vision)

**Items**: Blindfold of True Darkness (Arms & Equipment, but not sure if this is 3.5 or Pathfinder), Swordmasters Blindfold (only 5ft, but comes with Locate Weakness)

There looks to be discussion about it here as well: [playing-a-blinded-character-in-low-levels](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/38367/playing-a-blinded-character-in-low-levels)